# Error in Hive Command Prompt while executing DESC FORMATTED Command

Tags: hive

I have a requirement where I need to get the CREATE TABLE statements for all the External table.
I used the script provided by other developers on StackOverflow and made changes for getting CREATE TABLE Statement

```
#Command to Execute sh ScriptName.sh <Hive_database_name>
#Create external table list for a schema
SCHEMA=$1

#define filenames
alltableslist=tables_$SCHEMA
exttablelist=ext_tables_$SCHEMA

#Get all tables Line 12
 hive -S -e " set hive.cli.print.header=false; use $SCHEMA; show tables;" 1> $alltableslist

sed -i '/WARN:/d' $alltableslist
#For each table check its type:
for table in $(cat $alltableslist)
 do

     #Describe table- line no 20
     describe=$(hive -S -e "use $SCHEMA; DESCRIBE FORMATTED $table")

     #Get type
     table_type=$(echo "${describe}" | egrep -o 'Table Type:[^,]+' | cut -f2)
     # echo $table "-" $table_type
     #Check table type, get create table statement
      if [ $table_type == EXTERNAL_TABLE ]; then
         echo Processing table $table ...
         #get CREATE TABLE SCRIPT and save results
         hive -e "use $1;show create table $SCHEMA.$table" >> $exttablelist
         echo  -e ";\n" >> $exttablelist
      fi

done; #tables loop
sed -i '/WARN:/d' $exttablelist
```

The script working fine till line no 12, and I got the list of all the tables in the Hive Database.
But the script fails at line no 20, giving below error.

```
Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/2.6.5.3016-3/0/hive-log4j.properties
OK
Time taken: 1.871 seconds
NoViableAltException(13@[1453:5: ( ( KW_DATABASE | KW_SCHEMA )=> ( KW_DATABASE | KW_SCHEMA ) ( KW_EXTENDED )? (dbName= identifier ) -> ^( TOK_DESCDATABASE $dbName ( KW_EXTENDED )? ) | ( KW_FUNCTION )=> KW_FUNCTION ( KW_EXTENDED )? (name= descFuncNames ) -> ^( TOK_DESCFUNCTION $name ( KW_EXTENDED )? ) | ( KW_FORMATTED | KW_EXTENDED | KW_PRETTY )=> ( (descOptions= KW_FORMATTED |descOptions= KW_EXTENDED |descOptions= KW_PRETTY ) parttype= partTypeExpr ) -> ^( TOK_DESCTABLE $parttype $descOptions) |parttype= partTypeExpr -> ^( TOK_DESCTABLE $parttype) )])
        at org.antlr.runtime.DFA.noViableAlt(DFA.java:158)
        at org.antlr.runtime.DFA.predict(DFA.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.descStatement(HiveParser.java:18250)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.ddlStatement(HiveParser.java:4182)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1786)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1152)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:171)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:447)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:330)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1233)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1274)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1170)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1160)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:217)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:169)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:380)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:315)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:712)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:685)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:243)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:158)
FAILED: ParseException line 1:15 cannot recognize input near 'FORMATTED' '_1xy_abcde00005' '<EOF>' in describe statement
```

I have total 75000 tables in the database, and around 1000 tables like _1xy_abcde00005

Can you please help?

Comment: i am curious - why you are using describe formatted? Do you need only create table or other stuff like structure etc.?

Comment: I am using describe formatted to check the type of table, if it is external or managed. If it is external, then only fetch the create table statement, not otherwise.